# Why Python round it to integer instead of float number?

Tags: python

I have code like this, where ROP is taken from excel (float numbers). After the loop val and count are float numbers and somehow Python round the result to integer. How to avoid this?

```
ROP = df['ROP fph'].values.tolist() 
ROP = np.array(ROP)             
ROPav = np.array([0]*len(ROP))

ave_width = 100
for i in range(len(ROP)):
    val = 0
    count = 0
    for j in range(ave_width):
        if i-j >= 0:
            val += ROP[i-j]
            count += 1
        if i+j < len(ROP):
            val += ROP[i+j] 
            count += 1
    ROPav[i]  = val/count
```

for example here the results for one line :

```
val = 16326.239
count = 200
val/count = 81.632
ROPav[i] = 81
```

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Operators Division and Type Conversion for details about the influence of your python version on division results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) says:

> dtype : data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will
>   be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the
>   sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array. For
>   downcasting, use the .astype(t) method.

You initialize with:

```
ROPav = np.array([0]*len(ROP))
```

Which makes this an int array. Try instead

```
ROPav = np.array([0.0]*len(ROP))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a data type or use a value with correct data type when calling `np.array`. Try:

```
ROPav = np.array([0.0]*len(ROP))
```